# ruby strptime format throws error for custom format "%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%9N %p"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strptime

I am trying to parse incoming csv files containing one field with date-time string using fluentd(written in ruby) but it throws error for provided custom time format.

To check whether I am using correct format, I wrote sample ruby code(not a ruby programmer so used online ruby IDE) and found that the format works well when I try to write using it but ruby throws error when I try to read using this format :

```
[ code ]

require 'time'

time = Time.new
puts "writing time : " + time.strftime("%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%9N %p")
newtime = Time.strptime("29-Sep-16 07.45.45.331680519 PM", "%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%9N %p")
puts "reading time : " + newtime

[ output ]

sh-4.3$ ruby main.rb                                                                                                                                    
writing time : 29-Sep-16 05.47.36.206929933 PM                                                                                                          
/usr/share/ruby/time.rb:427:in `strptime': invalid strptime format - `%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%9N %p' (ArgumentError)                                         
    from main.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

I checked many posts where people found issues with strptime but could not understand how to resolve above. Pls suggest.

Comment: `%9N`? What's that? When debugging problems like this start deleting things until it works, then put back stuff until it breaks. Then you've found your problem code.

Comment: @tadman : %9N specifies that value here is nanoseconds and has width 9 digits. I tried diff combinations like parsing only date, etc but strptime simply not working. Checked documentation for strptime but looks like my usage is correct, so not clear where is the error.

Comment: @tadman : Looks like you were correct in pointing out. %9N does not look to be supported though its mentioned here as supported - http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html. When I changed %9N to %N, the parsing was successful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem was with %9N - it is not supported. I changed %9N to %N and the parsing was successful.
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html specifies  formats like %3N, %9N etc for parsing milliseconds, nanoseconds.. but it doesn't seem to work.
Thanks to tadman for suspecting this specifier.